# How can I change the header color bar in jquery datepicker?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

Trying to set background color for header and title to light blue but no go.   Can somebody point me to the correct .ui-datepicker fields to set background color to blue for entire title as well as color of the days?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom theme using ThemeRoller: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

(or choose a close existing one)